# Issue with jQuery blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements firstName and lastName. I need to alert some text when focus out both elements. I used the jQuery as below.

```js
$(document).on("blur", "#fName", function(event) {
  alert("First Name lost the focus");
});

$(document).on("blur", "#lName", function(event) {
  alert("Last Name lost the focus");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="userReg">
  <input type="text" id="fName" name="firstName" />
  <input type="text" id="lName" name="lastName" />
</div>
```

But the issue here is even If I focus out the first element the second alert also prompting.

What is the issue here?

Comment: are they nested elements?

Comment: Yes. Both are in the same div.

Comment: Share the relevant markup and create a working snippet demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Doesn't looks like something really possible since the selector is unique for both.. Infact, a simple fiddle demonstrates that it works good https://jsfiddle.net/YuriJF/jamtwpjk/

Comment: I am not able to replicate this issue, can you share a working fiddle replicating your issue?

Comment: I works fine in Edge. Issue with Chrome. Focus the firstName and press Tab and try.

Comment: And with Opera too.

Comment: It is working fine on chrome for me.

Comment: Focus the firstName and press Tab and try

Comment: The issue you're describing usually results from the`alert` because if the message box pops up the focus is lost (`blurred') and then reentered etc.. that's why you get an endless loop of "blur".

Comment: Yes. You are correct xander. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @Java-Seekar don't use `alert`, just `console.log` for debugging, it's the better practice anyway. :)

Comment: This is a small POC. For the actual implementation I need to show the alert.

Comment: @Java-Seekar I'm just saying using alert in any way in modern web sites is considered bad practice and some browser might even block the alert box on some conditions. If you wan't a popup like that use [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or something that looks better anyway.

Comment: In my actual implementation I am using the popup. But I experience the same issue.

Comment: @xander has explained it why this is happening with alert, that is reason so avoid alert for blur events.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on("blur", "#fName", function(event) {
  console.log("First Name lost the focus");
});

$(document).on("blur", "#lName", function(event) {
   console.log("Last Name lost the focus");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="userReg">
  <input type="text" id="fName" name="firstName" />
  <input type="text" id="lName" name="lastName" />
</div>
```

It will work fine with "console.log" because on every time alert popups and on clicking it's "ok" button, blur event is definitely going to be call because cursor is still at your input control and you are clicking on button.